# How can I sum specific values of a column corresponding to unique values of another column, without using the "accumarray" command?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix in matlab:

```
a=[1 1; 1 2; 1 3; 2 1; 2 5; 2 7; 3 2; 3 1; 3 4];
```

if

```
a1=[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]; is the first column
```

and

```
a2=[1 2 3 1 5 7 2 1 4]; is the second column
```

of this matrix, I want for the repeated values "unique(a1)" of a1 to sum the corresponding values of a2, so as to get this:

```
a3=[1+2+3 1+5+7 2+1+4]=[6 13 7]
```

but without using the "accumarray" command
Any help please?

Comment: Whenever someone asks a question, then follows it with "without using ______ (tool that is explicitly intended for this purpose)" I'm left wondering why...

Comment: @tmpearce: Based on a comment on my answer I would guess that the OP uses an older Matlab version. Maybe `accumarray` wasn't implemented in his version?

Comment: Yes indeed. It is the 6.5 version

Answer (score 1):

My [consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354-consolidator) tool does this for you, even offering a tolerance.

```
[a1cons,a2cons] = consolidator(a1',a2',@sum)
a1cons =
     1
     2
     3

a2cons =
     6
    13
     7
```

Comment: ...and the tool is waay backward compatible!